# SparkSQL connection pooling

Tags: hive, datastax, apache-spark-sql

I have 4 node cluster in datastax 4.6 with 2 spark ,1 solr and 1 cassnadra node. I'm taking request for sparksql query execution (using hive context) from remote servers using java. In this process whenever I make connection to spark and use hivecontext, query execution take upto 2 mins. May be due to Hive metastore and as number of table grow more, its execution time increase.

Can anyone suggest any solution for it? Is object/connection pooling is the way ?

Thanks

Comment: How fast is the query in spark-shell?

Comment: In Spark shell also , first query in hive context is taking time.

Answer (score 0):

Spark is able to optimize map reduce by pulling data into RDD's in a lazy fashion. Unlike Hadoop, it only reads from disk when it has to and it caches the data in memory for faster access.

When you are reading from Cassandra in Spark there are a few tunables and some best practices that can help you optimize for performance:

1. Check out how [stages](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/common-spark-troubleshooting) work as your job executes. Finding out which stage is taking time will help you figure out how to best optimize it.
2. Use [LogicalPlan()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/ExplainCommand.html#logicalPlan()) in spark shell to see the steps spark will take to execute.
3. If you're doing [shuffles](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/3_selection.md#grouping-rows-by-partition-key), avoid them - they remove the benefits of data locality.
4. Optimize your [split size and page row size](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#configuration-options-for-adjusting-reads) for faster reads.

Have you tried comparing performance between SparkSQL and HiveContext? Although SparkSQL is not yet fully mature, it will continue to be developed and improved in the long term where hive context may not. Use SparkSQL when possible.